# How to have two classes point to the same Pandas Dataframe (pass by reference)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to have two classes which have access to the same dataframe so that if one class instances makes a change, it would be reflected in the other class.

Below I have a small example where `myDF` class holds the dataframe. It is instantiated in the `Book` class. `Journal` class also has an attribute for dataframe, and I want the `Journal` class instance to have the dataframe instance as one the `Book` class have.

Namely, when I call `update` on the `Book` instance, I want it to also update the dataframe in the `Journal` class instance.

```py
import pandas as pd

class myDF:
    def __init__(self):
        self.df = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 1}])
        
    def changeDF(self, df):
        self.df = pd.concat([self.df, df])

class Book:
    def __init__(self):
        self.DFObj = myDF()

    def update(self, df):
        self.DFObj.changeDF(df)

class Journal:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

b = Book()
j = Journal(b.DFObj.df)

print(j.df is b.DFObj.df) # True

row = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 2}])
b.update(row)

print(j.df is b.DFObj.df) # False

j.df # still original dataframe with 1 row, want two rows.
```

Comment: Simply don't do this. Pass an instance of `myDF` into `Book` as an argument. This technique is called dependency injection and you should read more about it. It's very important to understand the concept of dependency **inversion,** (where dependency **injection** is a technique for implementing dependency **inversion**).

Comment: Generally speaking, in OOP you usually want to minimize side effects. An object which depends on another object which could change its state at any time isn't a stable design and can lead to really difficult to track down bugs, and other nightmares. Depending on what you're trying to do here, you may want to look into **inheritance.**

Comment: [Real Python](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/) has a really good article on the basics of OOP if you're feeling overwhelmed.

Comment: To actually address your use-case, you might look at the [observer pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), which may suit your needs well, if you truly need to use this one-to-many model.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, this is not a good practice. If you want to create classes which include methods of smaller classes you can use inheritence.

Here is an example:

```py
import pandas as pd

class myDF:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df
        
    def changeDF(self, df):
        self.df = pd.concat([self.df, df])

class Book(myDF):
    def __init__(self, df):
        super().__init__(df)

    def update(self, df):
        self.changeDF(df)

class Journal(Book):
    def __init__(self, df):
        super().__init__(df)
        
j = Journal(pd.DataFrame([{'a': 1}]))


row = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 2}])
j.update(row)

j.df
```

Ouptut

```
    a
0   1
0   2
```

Comment: This is a fine example, but I think it'd be more appropriate for `Book` and `Journal` to both inherit from a generic base class which itself inherits from `myDF`. No matter what, OOP isn't a light subject and I OP is not overwhelmed.

Comment: @ddejohn, That's correct. I tried to keep OP's idea of `Journal` being a form of `Book`. Exactly, the subject needs more than a single answer.

Comment: I don't know if it's just for demonstration purposes, but you don't need to define the `__init__` methods of `Journal` and `Book` since they don't add any extra functionality.

Comment: @rodalm, You are right. It is assumed that in reality each Class will have its unique functionality and attributes.

Comment: It's hard to tell what is the best option here... Inherantance or passing the same `myDF` instance to both `Journal` and `Book` constructors.   It really depends on OP's ultimate goal, which is not clear. Also, there is a good chance that this is an XY problem and there is a simpler solution ;)